# How to specify parameters with Graph API POST?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have a post I want to comment on using the API. According to the doc's:

You can write to the POST_ID/comments connection to post a comment to the post by issuing an HTTP POST request with the publish_stream permission and following parameters.

```
Parameter    Description     Type    Required
message Comment text    string   yes
```

So I'm pressure that the API call looks like this:

```
$postId = "1234567890";
$facebook->api($postId."/comments", 'POST');
```

But where do I specify the message parameter?

I tried:

```
$facebook->api($postId."/comments", 'POST', array("message"=>"hello world");
```

but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Your postID may not accuracy.

As far as I know, facebook's postID may have several segment

such as a postId of a post on a fan page will have the following format :

PAGEID_POSTID

ex : 3201235968_1234567890

Good luck